# Function as parameter (DART)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to understand how dart uses a function as parameter. I wrote this code...

```
typedef Future<String> myFunction();

void main() {
  A a = A();
  a.f1(a._f1);
}

class A {
  f1(myFunction func) async {
    String x = await _f1;
    print(x);
  }

  Future<String> _f1() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((f) {
      return "test";
    });
  }
}
```

I need the function f1 returns "test", but I have this error : A value of type 'Future Function()' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'

If I change  String x = await _f1 by Future x = await _f1 I have another error.. I tried a lot of 
combinations, all of them fail.

Can someone fix my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
String x = await _f1;
```

The parameter for the method is `func`, so you are referencing the `_f1` method directly here rather than the parameter. Furthermore, rather than *calling* the method you are just referencing the method directly. In essence, you are trying to assign a `Function` to a variable that expects a `String`, which is what the error message is trying to tell you.

You need to reference the *parameter* and then you need to call it.

```
String x = await func();
```

---

As an aside, your `_f1` method is currently returning `null`. This is because you are returning a value from the method within the `then` but you aren't returning anything to `_f1` itself, which makes Dart default to returning `null`. You have to either return the future itself:

```dart
Future<String> _f1() {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((f) {
    return "test";
  });
}
```

or you need to switch to `async/await` syntax (my personal recommendation):

```dart
Future<String> _f1() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
  return 'test';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To execute a function you need to add brackets `( arguments )` after its name. It doesn't matter function is a variable or predefined one (constant).

Please check out this examples:

### Example 1.

```dart
Future<int> add(int a, int b) async {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)).then((f) {
    return a + b;
  });
}

Future<int> test(Future<int> Function(int a, int b) func) async {
  return await func(3, 2);
}

void main() {
  test(add)
    .then(print); /// will return result of 3+2 after 2 seconds
}
```

[Run this code](https://dartpad.dev/0ba874e090585b8275b23b9d6a676277)

### Example 2.

```dart
String Function(String, String) mergeFunction = (String a, String b) {
  return a + b;
};

void main() {
  print(mergeFunction('Hello ', 'world'));
}
```

[Run this code](http://dartpad.dev/a900d145a95d7b1810de833b91211218)